# How to divide time range in intervals if Start Time is greater than End time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm accepting time range from user in a 24 hr clock format.My code below works if the start time is less than End time. The following code divides the given time range with the interval.

How should I deal with a situation where Start Time is less than End Time. E.g. If Start Time is say 21:00 (9 PM) and End time is 03:00 (3 AM). Any idea how should I divide the time range where Start time is MORE than End Time?

```
DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStartTime.Text.Trim(),"HH:mm", null);
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEndTime.Text.Trim(), "HH:mm", null);

int interval = Convert.ToInt32(txtSessionDuration.Text.Trim());
for (DateTime i = start; i < end; i = i.AddMinutes(interval)) 
{
       //some code goes here...
}
```

Comment: Is the question how to detect scenario X ? Or how should you handle scenario X ?

Comment: Maybe you are asking "How should I deal with situation where Start time is MORE than End Time"? Because in your example (21:00 / 03:00) you have exactly this situation

Comment: Can you please be _more_ specific what exactly try to do and expected result?

Comment: All I'm doing is diving the time range with a given time interval. E.g. if the interval is 20 mins and time range is 8 am - 10 am. Then I'm writing 8:20, 8:40, 9:00, etc. to a file.  My code fails if the time range spans over midnight in which case Start time is more than End time. I need help as how do I divide time range when start time is greater than end time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is no user error and user want to get intervals, when end time is less than start time.

As `DateTime` contains not only time component, but date component, so we can simply add one day if end time is less than start time. You should modify you code as follows:

```
    DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStartTime.Text.Trim(),"HH:mm", null);
    DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEndTime.Text.Trim(), "HH:mm", null);
    if (end < start)
    {
        end = end.AddDays(1);
    }

    int interval = Convert.ToInt32(txtSessionDuration.Text.Trim());
    for (DateTime i = start; i < end; i = i.AddMinutes(interval)) 
    {
           //some code goes here...
    }
```

After you have parsed `DateTime` from string - both `start` and `end` contains equals date component. This mean that `end` time is *earlier* than `start` time. But if you passing `end` time, that is less than `start` time, you actually mean, that `end` time is time of next day.

So, if time component of `end` is less than it of `start` you can simply add 1 day to `end` and you will have ability to iterate from `start` to `end`.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I deal with a situation where Start Time is less than End
>   Time?

Don't you can compare theirs [`.TimeOfDay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday) properties? Like;

```
if(start.TimeOfDay < end.TimeOfDay)
```

Or instead of that, you can parse them to [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan) and compare directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by

```
DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + txtStartTime.Text.Trim(),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null);
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + txtEndTime.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null);

if(start.TimeOfDay < end.TimeOfDay)
{
     // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + ...`? Why would OP need this? o.O

Answer (score 0):

Use timespan:

```
DateTime departure = new DateTime(2010, 6, 12, 18, 32, 0);
DateTime arrival = new DateTime(2010, 6, 13, 22, 47, 0);
TimeSpan travelTime = arrival - departure;  
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}", arrival, departure, travelTime);      
// The example displays the following output:
//       6/13/2010 10:47:00 PM - 6/12/2010 6:32:00 PM = 1.04:15:00
```

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx